# A "--" operator in while loop function

Tags: c, iar

I am coding in C on a IAR compiler and have two while loops:

```
i= 5;
do {
    Task_sleep(1000);
}while(i-- && !Ready);

if (!Ready)
   {
      dprint("No ready response!");
      return false;
   }
```

And

```
i= 5;
do {

    Task_sleep(1000);
    i--;
}while(i > 0 && !Ready);

if (!Ready)
       {
          dprint("No ready response!");
          return false;
       }
```

The first will skip over the while loop and the second works properly.  The "Ready" bool is set in another thread.  The first loop will return false and the second will pass so Ready is not getting set to true.

I am thinking the compiler does not know how to handle the i-- in the while and is setting it to false.  Is there something else that could be going on?  With my setup I cannot step through the code in debug.

Edit Added to functions:

```
if(!Ready)
{
 dprint("No Ready responce!");
return false;
}
```

Tested Ready as volatile, --i instead of i--, and removing Ready.  All failed.  Testing:

```
}while(((i--) > 0) && !Ready);
```

Still fails, it has to be the IAR compiler not reading the i-- properly and needs to have the -- operation removed from the while function.  Let me know if you guys have anything else I can try but I feel confident in closing this issue.

Comment: In the first one, you aren't comparing your `i--` to anything, to match the second one, shouldn't it be `while(i-- > 0 && !Ready)`?

Comment: @gmiley eh? isn't is implied?

Comment: @gmiley: no. As far as the `while` is concerned, `i--` evaluates to either `true` (when `i != 0`) or `false` (when `i = 0`) – both checked before the actual decrement.

Comment: Why would it be? All `i--` does is decrement the `i` variable by 1.

Comment: a `do` loop is always executed at least once .. are you saying you're not even getting a single `Task_sleep()` with the first loop?

Comment: @gmiley: so according to you, this `i = 5; do { printf ("%d\n", i); } while (i--);` will not work? (Beware: I tested it.)

Comment: put a printf inside the first loop before the sleep.  I bet something gets printed out.

Comment: Is the `Ready` variable a volatile one? If not, the compiler may be short-circuiting this.

Comment: Nevermind, that is correct, any non-zero is true, zero is false. I just always explicitly type out my comparisons. The only alternative is that `Ready` is set to `true` still. Try printing out the current value of `Ready` in your loop.

Comment: Also, you might want to tag the question with [iar] in case that's something weird with their compiler.

Comment: I suspect the real problem here has nothing to do with `i` and everything to do with `Ready`. Completely agree with what @RadLexus said. It could also be some kind of race condition between the thread setting `Ready` and the one here reading it... not enough code to tell.

Comment: I think it is going into the loop once but it looks like the i-- is being set to false when i = 5.  I agree  "i-- > 0" is the correct way to write this on the first function, but was not sure if it was implied or up to the compiler on how it reads that.

Comment: You could always just `while (i--) if (!READY) Task_sleep (1000);`

Comment: I would remove `Ready` from the `while` condition entirely, then you can play with `i` as much as you want. Try `i--`, `--i` in the conditions, decrement `i` in the loop, whatever. That should tell you if it is in fact a problem with `i` or if `Ready` is throwing you a wrench

Comment: @John.Majzner -- do *NOT* delete parts of your questions. It is fine to *ADD* to your question as much as you want, but don't delete. That makes all previous answers appear out of context and it not helpful to others.

Comment: Show the assembly corresponding to each case

Comment: does the code (properly) initialize the `Ready` variable to 0/false before entering the posted loop?

Comment: Which CPU are you using? For, MSP430 and AVR, the IAR tools provide an intrinsic, `__delay_cycles()` that insert code that waits a specified number of cycles. This code will not be touched by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing post-decrement with pre-decrement operators.  The two operators are different.  Both `i--` and `--i` will decrement `i`.  But their values are different.  The value of `i--`, the post-decrement operator, is the *old* value of `i`.  The value of `--i`, the pre-decrement operator, is the *new* value of `i`.

Comment: I don't know what OP means by "The first will skip over the while loop",, but if `i` starts out at 5 he should get some looping regardless of post/pre-decrement operator used. Of course the loop is also dependent on `Ready`...

Comment: The "Ready" is set to true after ~3s.  On the first loop it looks like it waits for 1s then keeps going.  On the second loop it waits the 3s and then moves on.  "Ready" is set to false  in the first function causing it to fail later in the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code:

```
do {
    Task_sleep(1000);
}while(i-- && !Ready);
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
int condition;
TOP:
Task_sleep(1000);
condition = (i != 0 && !Ready);
i = i - 1;
if (condition)
    goto TOP
```

Your second code:

```
do {

    Task_sleep(1000);
    i--;
}while(i > 0 && !Ready);
```

is equivalent to this:

```
int condition;
TOP:
Task_sleep(1000);
i = i - 1;
condition = (i > 0 && !Ready);
if (condition) goto TOP;
```

The loops are different.    `i` is decremented at a different time relative to the time the condition is evaluated, and the comparison on `i` within the condition is different.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using `volatile` keyword to qualify variable `i` in the first version. I met a similar problem last week.